# Adding line numbers to parsing errors without extending Positional directly

Tags: scala, parsing, line-numbers, parser-combinators

I have (finally) completed a parser, which processes my DSL and translates it to my domain objects. Now I want to add some proper error handling, and I wish to add the line numbers to the errors reported by the parser.

The examples and answers I found [here](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/plugins/viewsource/viewpagesrc.action?pageId=917624) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906674/how-to-further-improve-error-messages-in-scala-parser-combinator-based-parsers) seem to indicate that I have to modify my domain objects to extend `scala.util.parsing.input.Positional`. The example is a bit too simplistic for my case, and (due to my inexperience) it seems my case doesn't quite fit this paradigm.

The main problem I have is that I do not want my domain objects to directly extend `Positional`. They are used elsewhere in the program that does not have anything to do with the parsing (the parser is just an extension of the program to create a different way to input the data). Also, I don't know how to handle cases which output `String` (or other classes which I don't have any control of). There is also the issue that my domain objects already extend other objects of the program, I can't simply change the hierarchy that way.

Is there any alternative way to handle this cleanly, without modifying the domain objects and coupling them with the `Positional`? (Apologies if I am asking something trivial that has to do with implementing traits etc. because I am still new to Scala)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator to build something like this

```
type Token = String

trait TokenIterator extends Iterator[Token] {
  def next: Token
  def hasNext: Boolean
  def pos: Int
}

class Tokenizer(regexStr: String, input: String) {
  val regex = regexStr.r

  def iterator: TokenIterator = new TokenIterator {
    val iter = regex.findAllIn(input)
    var pos = 0
    def next = {
      val n = iter.next
      pos = iter.start
      n
    }
    def hasNext = iter.hasNext
  }
}

val str = "3 + 4 - 5"
val iter = new Tokenizer("""d+|\S+?""", str).iterator

while(iter.hasNext) {
  val token = iter.next
  val pos = iter.pos
  println(pos + ": " + token)
}
```

Comment: How do I use this in my parser though? I have a parser of around 300 lines (quite a complex BNF). What do I change to integrate this?